# Active in Questions but not Following?

Tags: discussion, area-51, definition-phase

It seems some Area51ers like to be active in a proposal's questions (as in composing questions, commenting, and voting) without following it.

Wouldn't following be the most basic involvement in a proposal, and then asking and voting on questions would be for those a little bit more engaged?

For example the [Ebay](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/19315/ebay) proposal (actually, ahem, one of mine) has added no followers in two days but ten questions and plenty of voting and comments.

I am not criticising, and I'm glad of the interest in the questions. Just wondering.

Answer (score 1):

Asking good on or off topic questions, can be an interesting challenge that yields reputation. I suspect that's why many like to ask or answer questions.

Also the result of questions and their votes might be the reason for you to follow a proposal or not.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few proposals that I wanted to help with questions without following as the subject itself is of no interest to me, yet I feel capable to help. Voting might be considered more controversial, as I would help to form the page (adding 1/20 to a possible acceptance of a question as good example for on or off topic).

Yet the questions submitted in the first phase do not prominently show up in the beta site. Try finding the off topic questions in [WebApps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) - I was not able to.

Therefore I think that in the beta phase the page will be shaped and formed to its at least temporary final domain, which means that even voting on questions at most will give a temporarily wrong picture of the path the site is heading. Yet comments and the gang of followers can easily outweigh the few votes and questions received by non followers.

Therefore I only see a problem if the majority of question posters and voters do not follow and that causes your site to divert heavily from its stated purpose. Then maybe moderators are willing to help.

Of course, your concern is more in how to collect all the followers that you need to proceed. ell, you don't, you only need 5+5 questions. After that you need committed people. And I made myself only follow proposals I will most assuredly commit to afterwards.

So, in short, I guess it is no problem to vote and post questions to pages one does not follow.

Comment: "Try finding the off topic questions in WebApps - I was not able to." why would you? They were already deemed off-topic, why should anyone ask them then?

Comment: @Tobias - I was talking about the FAQ, for example. It is clear that those questions should not be posted again, but the effort made selecting them values for an entry in the FAQ. Yet, that it does not happen shows my point made here.

Comment: @Ralph: I see, sorry for misunderstanding. I think I read the FAQ will be shaped during beta and the whole example question business is only to be considered a draft. But I also think [voting without following should be restricted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53032/voting-and-posing-example-questions-should-only-be-allowed-for-followed-proposals).

Answer (score 0):

Let's get the blatant plug out of the way first: [WikiSpeedia](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/13716/wikispeedia). =:-)

As someone pretty guilty of this, I obviously don't have a problem with it. On my own proposal ([WikiSpeedia](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/13716/wikispeedia) - did I mention that?) I welcome the **best** questions that define the proposal - doesn't matter where they come from.

But, of course, I like people to sign up as well. ([WikiSpeedia](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/13716/wikispeedia), thanks for asking.)

Comment: 371 total chars, 134 of which are plug.  Too far, man.

Comment: @Popular - chill out, just having a joke. Hardly a reason to downvote, especially as I gave an honest and, I think, useful answer.

Comment: @Mark, yeah, okay, fine.  I was on the fence about the vote.  And at least you didn't make them stealth referral links.  Still, that's a lot of plug, and it doesn't really make a point about the topic at hand.

Comment: @Popular - thanks! I really *was* trying to make a joke - I didn't think anyone would be seriously impressed by a three time plug like that! (Even I'm not that dopey...) I did a plug because the questioner did - usually I don't (and it doesn't help anyway). I thought it was obviously a joke because of all the words in brackets? Anyway, sorry for any offence.

Comment: Seriously about the point, I really do welcome questions from people who aren't following because the most important part of the definition phase is getting the best questions - that gets the best definition of the proposal. OK, it's joint most important, with followers.

Comment: @Mark, I knew it was a joke, I just thought it was overdone.  Different tastes in humor, &c.